# How to start a function on click and/or on submit

Tags: ajax

i want to start a ajax call. Ones i start the call on click at a button (a tab-bar from a modal), this call loads the formular data in the modal. After that i have to send the form.

So is there a shorter way as what i do

1)

```
$('#nav-register-tab').click(function()
    {...do the ajax call...}
```

2)

```
$("#ajax_form").on("submit", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    {...do the same ajax call..}
```

In my case i have double sourcecode for the same ajax call.

Is there a way to comibine in way like

```
"$('#nav-register-tab').click or $("#ajax_form").on("submit"...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe there is a better way to do it, for the moment i put the ajaxcall in a function and call it on click or on submit. In this way i spend the double sourcecode.

```
$("#abc").on("submit", function (event) 
{   event.preventDefault();
    do_ajax_call($('#abc').serialize());  });

$('#def').click(function(){ do_ajax_call(false); });

function do_ajax_call(data){...}
```